# Wine "alt tabs" the game everytime there is a video playing

Tags: wine, video

I have a weird issue in Xubuntu 20.04. When I am playing a game and there is a video cutscene, the games "alt tabs" and I am back at the desktop. I need to click the game windows indicator to go back to the game.

Its really annoying and it happens in all the games when they have vide intros.

For instance : USF4, StreetFighterXTekken, Toy Story 3, etc.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

So, as a workaround I was able to "fix" this by running:

```
winecfg
```

and then selecting to run apps "with a Virtual Desktop".

This obviously should not be the right path but I do not have an explanation nor a proper fix.